# Ajax Tools App Exchange dojo.js not found

Tags: soql, appexchange, ajax-toolkit

Whenever I try to use Ajax Tools installed in any of my Dev Orgs and load it's Explorer tool, I receive a 404 (Not Found) error message preventing me from using the SOQL builder tool that's built into it as it has two dependencies.

Here are the error messages:

> https://na15.salesforce.com/js/dojo/0.4.1/dojo.js  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> servlet.Integration:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: dojo is not defined
>   servlet.Integration:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: dojo is not defined

I can't find where it's a known issue but it seems to happen in all of my Dev Orgs regardless of the SF Instance or machine that I access them with.

Is there any way this can be resolved? I've not found a SOQL builder that works nearly as well for me as the one that's in that tool where I can add fields from related objects to a query with just the click of the button (including automatically creating subqueries).